# Change the collapse direction bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

When I click on the button I want it to open up from the bottom and collapse back down rather than like a dropdown.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both elements</button>
  </p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the first collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the second collapse component of this multi-collapse example. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please copy all the relevant parts of your fiddle IN the question (perhaps as a  working snippet)

Comment: Bootstrap 5 doesn't require jQuery. It shouldn't be included unless it's actually needed. Also, I've updated your Bootstrap version to the latest. You should be using that.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#dropup) for dropup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle you are loading bootstrap 3.x script, which is inconsistent with the styles, which are 5.X.

Independent of the version, a solution for your request is to use a **dropup**.

Here's a running snippet using version 5:

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<!-- Default dropup button -->
<div class="btn-group dropup" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup 2
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: While you're right, we really shouldn't be recreating Bootstrap's documentation here.